# Deny url from being allowed

Tags: php

I have a short url site where i only one specific url to be used when you create a url and have this function to deny any other.

Someone people are now trying to add different url infront of the allowed url to create malware urls or redirect to php files. If example.com is the only allowed domain they try to created a short url with "example2.com/index.php/example.com" in the front to get past the function.

I wonder if it is possible to change something in the function or how i should do to be able to deny these people from doing this ?

```
function denyNon($url)
    {
        $strAllow = 'example.com'; 
        $strBase  = getBaseUrl($url);
        if(strpos($url, $strAllow) === false)
        {
            return true;
        }
                
}
```

Comment: Try using a URL parser like PHP's `parse_url`. This will give you an array and one of its keys is the exact domain.

Comment: Alternatively you could check for `http://example.com` and `https://example.com` and make sure `strpos` returns exactly `0`

Comment: As it is currently written, your `strpos` function is only validating that the URL contains your allowed URL, but it's not checking where it is. Using `parse_url` would be a much more effective method

Answer (score 1):

Use `parse_url` to check:

```
function denyNon($url)
{
    $strAllow = 'example.com'; 
    $parsed_url = parse_url($url);
    
    if ($parsed_url['host'] !== $strAllow)
    {
       // do something, the user requested a disallowed URL
    }

    else
    {
       // the URL matches the allowed domain
    }                        
}
```

For what it's worth, `parse_url` produces an array like this:

```
print print_r(parse_url('https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url'),true);

Array
(
    [scheme] => https
    [host] => www.php.net
    [path] => /manual/en/function.parse-url
)
```